# Using mapped handlers in a Golang web server

Tags: go, webserver

I need to define request handlers for specific requests in my Golang web server.  The way I am doing this at present is as follows

```
package main

import "net/http"

type apiFunc func(rg string, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)

func h1(rg string, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Bonjour"))
}

func h2(rg string, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Guten Tag!"))
}

func h3(rg string, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Good Morning!"))
}

type gHandlers map[string]apiFunc

var handlers gHandlers

func handleConnection(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    hh := r.URL.Query().Get("handler")
    handlers[hh]("rg", w, r)
}

func main() {
    handlers = make(map[string]apiFunc, 3)
    handlers["h1"] = h1
    handlers["h2"] = h2
    handlers["h3"] = h3
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleConnection)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

This works just fine.  However, I am still a newcomer to Golang so it may not be the "right" way to do things.  I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to indicate whether is a better way to go about achieving this result

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `switch` statement in `handleConnection`?

```
switch hh {
case "h1":
    h1("rg", w, r)
case "h2":
    h2("rg", w, r)
case "h3":
    h3("rg", w, r)
default:
    // return HTTP 400 here
}
```

The advantages are:

- Simpler to understand code:

  - no `apiFunc` and `gHandlers` types
  - no need to browse around the source code in order to understand the routing logic, it is all in one place
- More flexible: you can call functions with different arguments and implement more complex routing rules if necessary.

Comment: I generally tend to assume that a lookup table is faster than any kind of runtime conditional evaulation. This [SO  thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928221/table-of-functions-vs-switch-in-golang) would appear to support that assumption.  That apart all of my code is emitted by a script, not written by hand and it turns out to be cleaner/more efficient to emit a lookup table.

Comment: @DroidOS, the thread you mentioned is from 2012. It is possible that the latest Go compiler produces faster code. E.g. https://github.com/golang/go/commit/4bc9badd759f863f784e5f8d105a25c615324359 If performance is really important I would suggest you to benchmark two different approaches.

Comment: @DroidOS, if the code is auto-generated and no one looks at it other than Go compiler than I think it doesn't really matter if it is idiomatic or not. Just make it as efficient as possible. Look at stringer output for example (http://blog.golang.org/generate).

Comment: I just mentioned the possible speed issue in passing. The more important issue here is that emitting the lookup table is cleaner & faster than building a lengthy `switch` statement